# Is only manual testing enough to get a job offer?

Tags: manual-testing

My name is Prakash amd I'm from mechanical engineering stream.

I did a job for about 1 year and 10 months in mechanical field.

Now I want to change my profile as a testing engineer.

IF I LEARN ONLY MANUAL TESTING can I get any job offers?

Comment: Great question!

Comment: can you please mark an answer if you have found anything useful here, so people will get some recognition for their effort? thanks

Answer (score 3):

**YES**

1. Manual testing is a very important part in software quality assurance industry.
2. Some people may argue it does not require any particular skills, but they are wrong; the reason they say this is most of time, manual testers are role-playing customers / end users, by default, customers/ end users do not need any particular skills to use a piece of software. But this is not true, as a manual tester, you need to apply various techniques to design, plan, execute a test case, you also need to uses your imagination to role-play different customers, you also need to have a good inter-person skills to talk to a developer when you discover a bug, you also need to be very organized to follow up a bug after it is raised.
3. Many if not all, software companies look for manual testers, plenty of career opportunities out there.
4. If someone tells you a manual tester can be replaced by an automated tester, they are very wrong. Manual testers will always have their role in software industry.

Comment: To add to point 4: If someone says this, run away. Do not work for this person nor company. Even as an automation engineer. Life will become 30+ hours every week of fixing broken tests that never should have been written in the first place

Comment: @PaulMuir, it is surprising how many people actually believe automated testing can replace manual testing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can get a job in software industry. But you can't get more package just with manual testing. If you learn automation as well then you can demand a good package and concentrate on Quality Assurance(QA) which has good future.

QA: Software Quality Assurance is to provide management with appropriate visibility into the process being used by the software project and of the products being built.

Testing (QC): You can't explore much.

Still if you want to enjoy manual testing, try to get job in any design based companies (In my opinion) because in product based companies we have to focus more on functional testing. Whereas, in design companies we need to test for pixel perfection manually.

Comment: What does QC stand for?

Comment: Quality Control: Product quality is compared with the applicable standards (Will test with reference of design or predefined things ) and QA comes under Establishes and evaluates the quality of the product like finding root-causes (Defect Prevention).

Am new to this testing industry, put a comment if I defined wrongly. I written everything with my experience only. I am ready to take your inputs.

Comment: @PavanKumar better move this __QC descritpion__ into your answer

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.

From my experience there are two ways this can work:

- **The company believes testers don't need skills** - this is, sadly, common. These are the places where the junior testers follow detailed test scripts, often to the level of "click the Submit button" and the senior testers write the scripts. I think of this as the "any warm body" school of testing, and I see it far too often. I'd recommend avoiding these unless you're desperate.
- **The company wants context-driven manual testers** - By this I mean, the organization is looking for someone who can find problems quickly, document them in a way that's clear and easy to reproduce (assuming that the problem can be easily reproduced). This side of the testing divide is where you want to be - but these kinds of positions are harder to find because a lot of places focus much more on automation.

Comment: I've seen worse that no-skills testers. In one company, management believed **no training for testers or understanding tested app is necessary**. So they just clicked around and submitted reports if they did not understands something - most of reports was **correct** behavior which they lacked to understand.

Comment: @PeterMasiar - that's dreadful! The "any warm body" side of things is bad enough without that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. as a manual tester with little experience. Depends if any company needs such skills.

Comment: Buddy this is better off as a comment on another answer or the question itself!

Answer (score 0):

The entry requirements for manual testing are very low. Just having experience as an end-user is enough.
Being able to design test cases helps a lot, but It's even possible to work as a manual tester just by executing test scripts written by a senior tester.